# creating dynamic HTML Tables in code to an ajax request? JQuery vs MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Do you think it would be a better solution to create dynamic html tables on the server and send back HTML (server would have to generate the html) in response to ajax request or would it be better to send back the JSON and construct the html using jquery/javascript. I generally like to move as much processing to the client as i can but i don't know what would be considered preferable from a maintenance aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would almost never send full html from the server via ajax requests.  its just so heavy, especially if its going to be a repeated request.  check out [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) if you haven't already.

from a maintenance perspective, you could house each the templates in their own partial view and then include them as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Thats exactly what i was looking for. I just recently started with jQuery and didn't even know what jQuery Templates were but after looking at what they were it was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: yeah, its neat.  if you want something a little more lightweight check out javascript microtemplating.  here's a good example (http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).  it allows for a more native javascript feel for your templates, and its just an interesting concept.